# Limit String.split to a maximum number of elements

Tags: dart

In C#, the `Split` function can receive a `count` parameter, so the split returns a maximum of `count` elements:

```cs
var a = "a b c d e";
var r = a.Split(' ', 3);
// r is ["a", "b", "c d e"]
```

What's the simplest way to achieve this in Dart?

I think any of the following would be useful: obtaining the exact same list as shown, or obtaining the 3 elements in different variables.

Comment: Ahh, apparently stolen from the Perl split.

Comment: Ahh, apparently stolen from the Perl split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any built-in way to limit the number of results from `String.split`.

If you're splitting on a `String` and not on a `RegExp`, note that the [`String.split` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/split.html) states:

> If the pattern is a `String`, then it's always the case that:
>
> ```dart
> string.split(pattern).join(pattern) == string
> ```

which means that you could execute `String.split`, take the elements you want, and use `join` on the rest.  That would result in potentially a lot of wasted work, and it therefore wouldn't be efficient, though.

Here's an implementation that limits the maximum number of elements and that mostly follows the C# semantics:

```dart
extension PartialSplit on String {
  /// A version of [String.split] that limits splitting to return a [List]
  /// of at most [count] items.
  ///
  /// [count] must be non-negative.  If [count] is 0, returns an empty
  /// [List].
  ///
  /// If splitting this [String] would result in more than [count] items,
  /// the final element will contain the unsplit remainder of this [String].
  ///
  /// If splitting this [String] would result in fewer than [count] items,
  /// returns a [List] with only the split substrings.
  List<String> partialSplit(Pattern pattern, int count) {
    assert(count >= 0);
    
    var result = <String>[];

    if (count == 0) {
      return result;
    }
    
    var offset = 0;
    var matches = pattern.allMatches(this);
    for (var match in matches) {
      if (result.length + 1 == count) {
        break;
      }

      if (match.end - match.start == 0 && match.start == offset) {
        continue;
      }
 
      result.add(substring(offset, match.start));
      offset = match.end;
    }
    result.add(substring(offset));

    return result;
  }
}

/// Prints a [List] of [String]s with less ambiguity.
///
/// The normal conversion of a `List<String>` to [String] would result in
/// ambiguity when printing `[]` and `['']`.
///
/// (Don't use this in production code.  This does not escape embedded
/// quotes.)
void printStrings(List<String> strings) =>
  print([for (var s in strings) "'$s'"]);


void main() {
  // Prints: ['a', 'b', 'c d e']
  printStrings('a b c d e'.partialSplit(' ', 3));
  
  // Prints: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
  printStrings('a b c d e'.partialSplit(' ', 10));

  // Prints: []
  printStrings('a b c d e'.partialSplit(' ', 0));

  // Prints: ['a', 'b', 'cde']
  printStrings('abcde'.partialSplit('', 3));

  // Prints: ['a b c d e']
  printStrings('a b c d e'.partialSplit('_', 3));

  // Prints: ['']
  printStrings(''.partialSplit(' ', 3));

  // Prints: ['', 'a', 'b  c ']
  printStrings(' a b  c '.partialSplit(' ', 3));
  
  // Prints: ['', 'a', 'b', '', 'c', '']
  printStrings(' a b  c '.partialSplit(' ', 10));
}
```

I've added such an implementation of `partialSplit` to my [`dartbag`](https://pub.dev/packages/dartbag) package.  Based on lrn's comment below, I've also implemented and added a `lazySplit` extension method that returns an `Iterable<String>` that tokenizes a `String` lazily.

Comment: There is no way. The `split` function really should have been lazy, but it predates `Iterable`, and was never made right.
(I've considered making `split` be lazy, while pretending to return a `List`, but that list then lazily computes values only far as it needs to for the operations called on it.)

Comment: @lrn It's unfortunate that `split` is not lazy.  Returning a lazily-evaluated `List` would be pretty neat.  Another alternative would be to just add, say, a `static` method to `String` (or an extension method) that returns an `Iterable<String>`, and the existing `split` method could be reimplemented to leverage that.

Answer (score 1):

Since

> If the pattern is a String, then it's always the case that:
> `string.split(pattern).join(pattern) == string`

the simplest way (given your example of splitting by a fixed character rather than a pattern) would thus be to re-join the remaining elements:

```dart
var x = r[0]; // a
var y = r[1]; // b
var rem = r.sublist(2).join(' '); // c d e
```

or if you don't like the temporary sublist and would prefer an iterator:

```dart
var rem = r.getRange(2, r.length).join(' '); // c d e
```

you could then build the list as `[x, y, rem]`; in general, you could implement this as follows:

```dart
split(String str, String sep, int n) {
    var list = str.split(sep);
    if (list.length <= n) return list;
    return [...list.getRange(0, n-1), list.getRange(n-1, list.length).join(sep)];
}
```

now `split("a b c d e", ' ', 3)` would be `["a", "b", "c d e"]` as desired.

A more efficient implementation or an implementation with pattern support would probably repeatedly call `indexOf` with the `start` parameter set instead, likely at the cost of conciseness.